# Saving the result of applying a function to a variable in the same variable

Tags: haskell

I was remembering the haskell programming I learnt the last year and suddenly I had a little problem.

```
ghci> let test = [1,2,3,4]
ghci> test = drop 1 test
ghci> test



^CInterrupted.
```

I do not remember if it is possible.
Thanks!

Comment: You seem to be a Haskell beginner. I'd reccomend reading [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) to completion before asking question like this—LYAH covers this problem very quickly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`test` on the first line and `test` on the second line are *not*, in fact, the same variable. They're two different, separate, unrelated variables that just happen to have the same name.

Further, the concept of "saving in a variable" does not apply to Haskell. In Haskell, variables cannot be interpreted as "memory cells", which can hold values. Haskell's variables are more like mathematical variables - just names that you give to complex expressions for easier reasoning (well, this is a bit of an oversimplification, but good enough for now)

Consequently, variables in Haskell are *immutable*. You cannot change the value of a variable by assignment, like you can in many other languages. This property follows from interpreting the concept of "variable" in the mathematical sense, as described above.

Furthermore, definitions (aka "bindings") in Haskell are *recursive*. This means that the right side (the body) of a binding may refer to its left side. This is very handy for constructing infinite data structures, for example:

```
x = 42 : x
```

An infinite list of `42`s

In your example, when you write `test = drop 1 test`, you're defining a list named `test`, which is completely unrelated to the list defined on the previous line, and which is equal to *itself without the first element*. It's only natural that trying to print such a list results in an infinite loop.

The bottom line is: you cannot do what you're trying to do. You cannot create a new binding, which shadows an existing binding, while at the same time references it. Just give it a different name.